# QLabel gets added again and again during Date and Time update inside Timer in Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, datetime, timer, qlabel

I need to display Date and Time in QLabel in statusbar and update the Datetime label every second, To update datetime i added the update code inside Timer, Date and time gets updated every sec as expected, My problem is updated Label is added again and again in GUI, 
I posted my code below:

```
void MainWindow::setTaskBar()
{
    timer = new QTimer();
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateStatusBar()));
    timer->start(60000);

    updateStatusBar();
    resize(320,200);
}

void MainWindow::updateStatusBar(){

       QDateTimeEdit *dateTimeEdit = new QDateTimeEdit(this);
       dateTimeEdit->setDateTime(QDateTime::currentDateTime());

       QLabel *dlbl = new QLabel();

       dlbl->setText(dateTimeEdit->text());
       dlbl->update();
       statusBar()->addPermanentWidget(dlbl);
}
```

I have attached my window screenshot please check my label widget in status bar how it is repeated.

output screen

[image]

Comment: move "dlbl" as member variable and create the label in the constructor.

Comment: you should do the same for dateTimeEdit.